# Passing the value of a pointer correctly through recursion

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, struct, binary-search-tree

So I have a BST data structure and I want to create a function that finds the parent and rotates the nodes within. I have done this successfully, however, it doesn't update correctly the values in the tree, it only does it inside the function.

**MyBST.cpp:**

The node struct:

```
struct Node
{
    int key;    // the key stored by this node
    Node *left;   // the left child of this node
    Node *right;  // the right child of this node
};
```

Rotate Functions:

```
Node* MyBST::rotateRight(Node* Q)
{
    Node* P = Q->left;
    Q->left = P->right;
    P->right = Q;
    return P;
}

Node* MyBST::rotateLeft(Node* P)
{
    Node* Q = P->right;
    P->right = Q->left;
    Q->left = P;
    return Q;
}
```

findParentRotate function:

```
Node* MyBST::findParentRotate(int num)
{
    if ((root->right != nullptr && root->right->key == num) || (root->left != nullptr && root->left->key == num))
    {
        return root;
    }
    else {
        findParentRotate(num, root);
    }

    return nullptr;
}

Node* MyBST::findParentRotate(int num, Node *n)
{
    if ( (n->right != nullptr && n->right->key == num) || (n->left != nullptr && n->left->key == num) )
    {
        if (n->key < num)
        {
            n = rotateLeft(n);
            cout << "The value of node inside: " << n->key << endl;
            return n;
        }
        else {
            n = rotateRight(n);
            cout << "The value of node inside findParentRotate after rotation: " << n->key << endl;
            return n;
        }
    }
    else if (n->key > num)
    {
        findParentRotate(num, (n->left));
    }
    else {
        findParentRotate(num, (n->right));
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
cout << "Value of node in main.cpp before rotation: " << tree1.root->left->right->left->key << endl;
tree1.findParentRotate(5);
cout << "Value of node in main.cpp after rotation: " << tree1.root->left->right->left->key << endl;
```

I'm trying to change the value of MyBST tree1, but when I try and do that the value only changes inside the function I used, and not inside the main.cpp file. How should I call the pointers correctly so that the nodes stay the same all around.

Answer (score 0):

So it was a very basic mistake, in all honesty, I wasn't returning the values correctly. This is how I fixed it:

findParentRotate function:

```
void MyBST::findParentRotate(int num)
{
    root = findParentRotate(num, root);
}

Node* MyBST::findParentRotate(int num, Node *n)
{
    if ( (n->right != nullptr && n->right->key == num) || (n->left != nullptr && n->left->key == num) )
    {
        if (n->key < num)
        {
            n = rotateLeft(n);
            return n;
        }
        else {
            n = rotateRight(n);
            return n;
        }
    }
    else if (n->key > num)
    {
        n->left = findParentRotate(num, (n->left));
        return n;
    }
    else {
        n->right = findParentRotate(num, (n->right));
        return n;
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

I was missing the return functions, so that all the string of nodes were updated to the most current one.